# How to tag an image and push it to GitHub's registry?

Tags: docker, github, docker-registry

I currently run my own registry (based on [Docker Hub's image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry)) to which I push images I built from my code. It works fine.

I wanted to experiment with GitHub's registry and followed their [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-docker-for-use-with-github-packages#example-publishing-a-docker-image) (below is a summary of the steps in the doc):

> ```
> $ docker login -u USERNAME -p TOKEN docker.pkg.github.com
> $ docker build -t docker.pkg.github.com/octocat/octo-app/monalisa:1.0 .
> $ docker push docker.pkg.github.com/octocat/octo-app/monalisa:1.0
> ```

In my case, I built a minimal image (just `FROM alpine` in the `Dockerfile`) and tried to replicate:

```
> docker login -u WoJ -p f<...token...>9 docker.pkg.github.com
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded

> docker build -t docker.pkg.github.com/WoJ/docker_repository/testing2:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : FROM alpine
 ---> 965ea09ff2eb
Successfully built 965ea09ff2eb
Successfully tagged docker.pkg.github.com/WoJ/docker_repository/testing2:1

> docker push docker.pkg.github.com/WoJ/docker_respository/testing2:1
The push refers to repository [docker.pkg.github.com/WoJ/docker_respository/testing2]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: docker.pkg.github.com/WoJ/docker_respository/testing2
```

**How should I interpret this error?** Specifically: what should I do to correctly tag the image? (and how is this different from the documentation?)

The list of local images:

```
> docker images
REPOSITORY                                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
(...)
alpine                                                   latest              965ea09ff2eb        8 weeks ago         5.55MB
docker.pkg.github.com/WoJ/docker_repository/testing2   1                   965ea09ff2eb        8 weeks ago         5.55MB
```

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the URL of the Git repo (https://github.com/WoJ/docker_respository does not exist).

Comment: can you try again with e.g.: `docker build -t docker.pkg.github.com/woj/woj/testing2:1 . && docker push docker.pkg.github.com/woj/woj/testing2:1` ?

Comment: I voted to close the question (my own) because this is a typo → if someone can forcibly delete it is would be best. OTOH the answer was extremely helpful and I would like not to deplete the answerer from my +1 and accepted answer points...

Comment: @ErikMD: thanks - but is was a typo (per the answer and my comment above)

Comment: Do you just want that I close the question as off-topic?

Comment: @ErikMD: I voted to close, you did too I think - with a few more it will close by itself :) Thanks for the help  in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easy, lol :)

You have a typo!

You are building an image tagged as `docker.pkg.github.com/WoJ/docker_repository/testing2:1`

But pushing `docker.pkg.github.com/WoJ/docker_respository/testing2:1`

Check that part in the both names docker_re**po**sitory vs docker_re**spo**sitory :)